# Is there any relatively quick way to diagonalize this matrix with an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

3a of [this released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F03_Final_Exam-A.Liu_.pdf) asks (paraphrased):

> Diagonalize the matrix 
>   $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
>     0  & 4 & 0 \\
>     4  & 0 & 4 \\
>     0  & 4 & 0 
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   by an orthogonal matrix.

I tried using the standard calculate the eigenvalues $\lambda_{i} = 0, 2(1 \pm \sqrt{2})$ and getting the appropriate eigenvector matrix for:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & -1 & 1 \\
    -\sqrt{2}  & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
    1  & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

However if you multiply any permutation by the transpose, you get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 4 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

instead of $I_n$. I'm stuck. Is there an easier way to compute an orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes $A$?

Comment: The fastest *surest* way is to carry on Gram-Schmidt in your basis of eigenvectors and get thus an orthonormal basis from which construct a matrix $\;P\;$ for which $\;PAP^{-1}\;$ will be diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is not orthogonal.  Remember an orthogonal matrix has columns which are perpendicular **and unit length**.  So your first column should be
$$\frac12\pmatrix{1\cr-\sqrt2\cr1\cr}$$
and the others should be adjusted similarly.

**Comment**.  An *orthogonal* matrix is one with *orthonormal* columns.  The terminology is, frankly, very confusing, but it's been around a long time and it probably is not going to change :(

Comment: I learned orthogonal as $A\cdot A^{T} = I_n$ and I wasn't really aware of the orthonormality that needed preservation. Normalizing each vector gives an identity matrix. Thanks!

Comment: It's a useful alternative characterisation: for real square matrices, $AA^T=I$ iff the columns of $A$ are orthonormal.

Comment: Note, I didn't check your eigenvalues and eigenvectors, from other people's answers it appears that they are wrong.  But the principle is the same.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I calculated the eigenvalues twice in my notebook and copied the wrong ones down.

Answer (score 0):

Quick note, your eigenvalues are actually $0, \pm4\sqrt{2}.$ The easiest way to compute the eigenbasis is to find the null space of $A-\lambda I$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda.$ The orthogonal bases of the necessary null spaces are: 
$$\text{null}(A-0\cdot I) = \text{null}(A) = \Bigg\langle\left({
\begin{array}{c} 
  -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\0\\\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{array}}\right)\Bigg\rangle$$
$$\text{null}(A-4\sqrt{2}\cdot I) = \Bigg\langle\left({
\begin{array}{c} 
  -\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}}\right)\Bigg\rangle$$
$$\text{null}(A+4\sqrt{2}\cdot I) = \Bigg\langle\left({
\begin{array}{c} 
  \frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}}\right)\Bigg\rangle$$
These were easily found via Gaussian Elimination. Thus the matrix
$$Q = \left({
\begin{array}{ccc} 
  -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2}\\0 & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} &-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}}\right)$$
orthogonally diagonalizes $A$ since $A = Q \Lambda Q^T$ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix that diagonalizes 
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 4 & 0 & 4 \\
 0 & 4 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

is 
$$
P=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with the following formula:
$$
P \cdot A \cdot P^T=D
$$
and doing the calculation you obtain:
$$
D=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -4 \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 \sqrt{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

also note that $P$ is unitary:
$$
P\cdot P^t={I}_{(3)}
$$